# C++20 Constraints - Restrict typename TFunction to be a function (with certain signature)

Tags: c++, typescript

How to translate this TS Code into modern C++20 using lambdas and modern templating features?

**[Edit]**: The main question here is: How to restrict `typename TFunction` to be of type `Function` or even a more specific function with a given signuature?

```
interface Subscription<TFunction extends Function> {
  readonly subscriber: TFunction;
  unsubscribe();
}

class Subscriptions<TFunction extends Function = Function> {

  private _subscriptions: Subscription<TFunction>[] = [];

  subscribe(f: TFunction): Subscription<TFunction> {
    // ...
    const _subscription: Subscription<TFunction> = {
      subscriber: f,
      unsubscribe: () => {
        this._subscriptions = this._subscriptions.filter(s => s !== f);
      };
    };
    this._subscriptions = [...this._subscriptions, _subscription];
    return _subscription;
  }
}
```

Comment: @churill Yes, exactly. `TFunction extends Function` ist the main driving issue here. How to restrict `typename TFunction` to be a Function, or more specificly a Function of certain type (signature)?

Comment: @kalamar Yes, I think that's a good question. Here's the previous link with non-broken formatting, that's probably the way to go.  Probably it's the best to make  a concept `Function` and a concept `Subscription`. en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function types in C++ are expressed as types like `R(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3)` (denoting a function that takes three arguments of types `Arg1, Arg2, Arg3` and returns an `R`). You can take a pointer to such a function, which has the type `R(*)(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3)`.

A template will typically use one type parameter for `R` and a parameter pack to generalise over all parameter types, e.g. `template <typename R, typename... Args> /* something involving the type R(Args...) */`

If you want to include objects with appropriate `operator()` (especially lambdas), you can use `std::function<R(Args...)>` to type erase the specific type of each subscriber.

Something like

```
template <typename Sig>
struct Subscription
{
    std::function<Sig> subscription;
    void unsubscribe();
};

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Subscriptions
{
    std::vector<Subscription<R(Args...)>> subscriptions;
public:
    R notify(Args... args)
    {
        R result;
        for (auto & s : subscriptions) result += s.subscription(args...);
        return result;
    }
    Subscription<R(Args...)> subscribe(std::function<R(Args...)> s);
};
```

Because you have to be explicit about object lifetimes in C++, lambda captures are more complex, so the implementation of `unsubscribe` is going to be tricky, in particular `std::function<Sig>` is not equality comparable with itself.

Comment: Thank you! Especially the first paragraph of your answer is very valuable.